# how do I create a stand-alone executable with perl 6?

Tags: raku, rakudo

The OLD [Perl 6 faq](http://www.perl6.org/archive/faq.html) said: "Rakudo, a Perl 6 compiler based on Parrot, allows compilation to bytecode, and a small wrapper exists that can pack up a bytecode file and parrot into a single executable."

So, it was possible to create a stand-alone executable, but I can not find *any* docs explaining how to go about this, or if it's still possible. So, I turn to you. What is the appropriate set of incantations required to convert Perl 6 code into a stand-alone executable that will work on a system that does not have Perl 6 installed.

Comment: That's the old, archived FAQ you're looking at (note the `/archive/` in the URL).  The [current FAQ](https://doc.perl6.org/language/faq) doesn't mention it.

Comment: Does "pack up a bytecode file and parrot into a single executable" necessarily mean the executable will run on a machine without Perl on it? [My first executable from Perl 6](http://perlgeek.de/blog-en/perl-6/my-first-executable.writeback) shows how to create a "fake executable" that is dynamically linked to libparrot, which would fail if libparrot wasn't installed on the other system.

Comment: @cjm thanks for that. Updated the question to reference the fact that the FAQ was old and see if it's still possible.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot The section of the old faq was under "stand-alone executable" so yes. I saw the link you mentioned too but 2009 commentary / how-to on perl 6 just can't be trusted to be relevant anymore.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is not possible with current Rakudo on MoarVM. There's still some dust that needs to settle regarding module loading and automatic compilation, but once that has happened, I see no reason why this ability couldn't be reintroduced if there is sufficient demand.

Comment: @Stats4224: as far as I know, though I haven't really kept up with Perl6 development the last couple of months; the dust regarding automatic compilation has settled, so I'm not aware of any blockers stopping someone from taking a shot at implementing this...